# Очереди типа LIFO: последний зашёл - первый вышел

Tags: java

Изучаю java по книжке Шилдта java2, дошел до изучения классов и тут мне объясняют про класс Стэк. Объясните, пожалуйста, смысл этого класса человеческим языком. Зачем эти очереди типа LIFO: последний зашёл - первый вышел. И как вы в обучении справились c этой кашей? Вот, кстати, пример из книжки:

```
class Stack {
    int stck[] = new int[10];
    int tos;

    Stack() {
        tos = -1;
    }
    void push(int item) {
        if (tos == 9) System.out.println("Стек заполнен.")
        else stck[++tos] = item;
    }
    int pop() {
        if (tos < 0) {
            System.out.println("Стек пуст");
            return 0;

        } else return stck[tos--];
    }
}
```

Comment: За все время я ни разу на практике не встречал случая, где надо было бы применить эту очередь =), хотя можно предположить случай, например, в играх - ханойская башня или стек активити в андроиде

Comment: Короче голову мне лишним забивают)

Comment: очередь - это fifo, стек - lifo. смешивать их не стоит, назначение у них разное. есть еще дек...

кстати, в бухгалтерии знают что такое лифо и фифо, правда не знают что они называются стеком и очередью. забавные эти бухгалтера )

Comment: Простите за офтоп, но как голосовать против коммента?(см. коммент @Gorets)

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @zenith, сначала этот коммент был ответом. Тогди и заминусовали. Потом перенесли и минусы сохранились

Comment: @stck, скорее всего Вы правы, но достоверно можно сказать, только изучив историю изменений в базе (если она вообще есть).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стэк - структура данных реализующий эту дисциплину. Т.е. это такой массив данным в который что-то кладут в определенной последовательности, а достать могут только в обратной. Самое простое, что приходит в голову, это реализация парсера выражения с помощью [обратной польской нотации](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.92.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.B5) или парсера какого-нибудь языка с си подобным синтаксисом, реализация собственных регулярных выражений. Когда вы используете рекурсию, то неявно используется стэк (хотите вы того или нет) => как вариант можно применить в любых местах где используется рекурсия для замены оной. Как бы это глупо ни звучало, но стэк пригодится везде где необходима дисциплина обслуживания LIFO =).

На сколько я помню, Шилдт в своей книге приводит собственные реализации стэка, динамического массива и т.п. в учебных целях, так читатель ознакомится с основными структурами данных и их свойствами, и джаву подучит.

Answer (score 5):

В парсерах/интерпретаторах стеки вполне себе широко применяется для разбора выражений, учета вложенных структур и вложенных вызовов. Исключения в java видели? Вот вам стек.

История действий пользователя в приложении тоже может вполне себе быть стеком.